# Existence & Uniqueness Theorems - Why Be Complicated?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In Goursat's proof of the existence & uniqueness of solutions of first order differential equations ([Page 45-48 of the book](http://archive.org/stream/differentialequa028961mbp#page/n3/mode/2up)) he proves the theorem by differentiating the equation continuously, turning it into a Taylor series for $y$ & says the main question is then convergence of this power series (something ignored before Cauchy). He then compares it to a geometric series which he shows to converge. My question is why this isn't good enough, or why this isn't used as a proof in standard books? Why do they need to make it complicated, invoking the [Picard theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) or similar theorems?  Note that [this pdf](https://www.math.okstate.edu/~binegar/5233-S96/5233-l16.pdf) proves the theorem for second order PDE's using the exact same power series idea so it seems more general, & is certainly easier, than Picard to me, what am I missing?

Comment: Many solutions to differential equations are not analytic. So no Taylor series has a chance of converging to those solutions. For example $f'(x) = \beta(x)$ where $\beta(x)$ is a bump function, this has no analytic solutions.

Comment: @RyanBudney: the point is that the **differential equation** involves non-analytic functions.  A differential equation $y' = f(y,t)$ where $f$ is analytic will have analytic solutions.

Comment: Another reason people prefer proofs with less assumptions is that these proofs are frequently more informative.  The proof that ODEs have unique solutions that show Euler's method converges, this not only tells you how to approximate solutions "constructively" (even when no closed-form solutions exist) but they also give you usable estimates on the size of the error in your approximation over the entire interval of convergence (provided you have something like a Lipschitz bound on the ODE).  This is informative on how reliable simulations can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going off of the above comment: proving a statement about a function using the function's Taylor series assume that the function is expressible as some Taylor series, i.e. that the function is analytic.

However, if we want the statement to hold for non-analytic functions, we need to look beyond Taylor series. Again, as pointed out before me, stating that a function is smooth on $\mathbb R$ is [not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) [enough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) to guarantee that it is analytic.

Comment: Do you have any standard examples showing the necessity of this - not bump or ad-hoc functions but something normal-looking?

Comment: "Normal-looking" is a highly subjective term, which you might want to clarify. Really though, I can't think of any good examples off-hand, normal-looking or otherwise.

Comment: Certainly though, it may be the case that the solution to your ODE is not infinitely differentiable.  I'm sure a situation like that could give you a more "normal-looking" example.

Comment: What's the Taylor expansion for a delta or step function?

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan what relevance does your question have to this question or answer?  If you mean the series at $x = 0$, then neither function is differentiable (in the usual sense) at $x = 0$, so they wouldn't have a Taylor series at zero. In fact, the delta function isn't even a function in the usual sense.

Comment: Don't those arise in solutions to many differential equations? My point was to provide a possible example of what you were trying to say.

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan my answer here completely answered the original question. If you'd like an illustrative example, post a new question making it clear what you're looking for.